# In Power Query I would like to select a tab in a workbook based on the value in a cell in the current workbook

Tags: powerquery

I feel like this should be dead easy, but I'm really struggling to find the answer on the internet.

I have this code for my Power Query:

```ml
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("My File Path"), null, true),
    Parent_Sheet = Source{[Item="Parent",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Parent_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Name", type text}, {"DoB", type date}, {"Class", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

I just want to change where it says `Item="Parent"` to `Item="D15"`.

Any ideas?

I've read some suggestions about referring to cells within Power Query that talk about writing custom functions or creating a second query and stuff, this all seems to be very over complicated. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Is the `D15`cell from the same file (named `My File Path` here) or from the current Excel from where the query is executed ? In the first case, which sheet/tab ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to a range name, not a cell reference for PowerQuery.  Create a range name, here ***aaa***, that is referring to some cell (here cell **D15**). That cell/range should then contain the text you want to use for the **Item=** step

[image]

then change your PowerQuery code to reference that range

```
let Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("My File Path"), null, true), 
ItemName= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="aaa"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Parent_Sheet = Source{[Item=ItemName,Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I got myself to about the same conclusion at the same time, although didn't need to use a name in the end, although a name is probably a sensible option in case it moves.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the end, that was a lot harder going than it needed to be, but for anyone else looking for the answer:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("My File Path"), null, true),
    SheetName = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Admin"]}[Content]{14}[Column4],
    Sheet = Source{[Item=SheetName,Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],

in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Easy when you know how!

Comment: In general, range names are the way to go to prevent things from being moved